# Minimum number of Coins needed to make change?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve the one particular problem and I ended up reading this. [I read this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280809/is-this-the-correct-minimum-number-of-coins-needed-to-make-change)

Above link states the problem of changing the amount when coins are given in infinite amount. Solution for this problem requires DP with little bit of greedy approach.

My question is: **How to proceed when number of coins are limited for each type?**